# Lower bound on binomial tail

Tags: probability, information-theory, binomial-distribution

In something I am reading, the following statement is mentioned in passing as something obvious: if $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli with parameter $1/2 + \delta$, then $\mathbb{P}(\sum_{i=1}^n X_n < n/2) \ge \exp(-n\delta^2)$. However, I am not sure how to show this. [The inequality may also be ignoring constants.]

There is a lower bound in terms of entropy on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Tail_Bounds), but I am wondering if there is a simpler approach that gives the weaker result above.

Comment: One possibility to try: the Berry–Esseen theorem.

Comment: Berry-Esseen seems overkill. It looks like a pretty simply Chernoff bound application.

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist Wouldn't Chernoff bounds give an upper bound on the tail, not a lower bound?

Comment: Oops... Missed that.

Comment: I think this is very easy to do by typicality actually. Do you have a resource on this? For example Cover and Thomas or El-Gamal's book.

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist Do you mean "typical sets"? I am not familiar with this but I guess I can look it up... thank you for the reference.

Comment: Yeah typical sets, typical sequences. It will not be hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P_p$ denote the Bernoulli distribution with mean $p$.
Using [Sanov's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanov%27s_theorem),

$$\frac{1}{n} \log P_{1/2+\delta}^n\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \le n/2\right) \to -\min_{p \in [0,1/2]} \operatorname{KL}(P_p \| P_{1/2+\delta}) = - \operatorname{KL}(P_{1/2} \| P_{1/2+\delta}).$$
$$P_{1/2+\delta}^n\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \le n/2\right)  \to \exp(-n \operatorname{KL}(P_{1/2} \| P_{1/2+\delta})) \approx e^{-2n\delta^2}.$$
where we note $$\operatorname{KL}(P_{1/2} \| P_{1/2+\delta})
= \frac{1}{2}\log \frac{1/2}{1/2+\delta}+\frac{1}{2}\log \frac{1/2}{1/2-\delta}
= -\frac{1}{2} \log (1-4\delta^2) \approx 2\delta^2.$$